# Need help identifying dataset images belong to

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, computer-vision, image-recognition

I used this dataset a few years back but my computer died and I only have a few images left from it, I need the citation so that I can find the rest and cite the images properly. There were multiple angles of these small random household objects against a black background. I did a reverse image search but it wasn't helpful. Only thing I could find was [this paper](http://www.ijert.org/view-pdf/563/color-texture-features-based-image-retrieval-using-structure-wavelet) using them without citing them. Here are the images I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9LmX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

A colleague just informed me it's the COIL-100 dataset from Columbia University: http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/software/softlib/coil-100.php